# Neovim 0.9.1 can't open syntax.vim

Tags: neovim, linux-debian, runtimepath

I just installed Neovim v0.9.1 in a Debian 12 Bookworm Server system.
I installed it from its homepage(github) using the .tar.gz method (nvim-linux64.tar.gz)
I decompressed the archive in `/home/user/Apps/Neovim/nvim-linux64/`.

But whenever I use `nvim` I get this error:

```
E848: Can't open file /__w/neovim/neovim/build/nvim.AppDir/usr/share/nvim/syntax/syntax.nvim
```

And when I run `:checkhealth` command I get this error:

```
E5009: Invalid $VIMRUNTIME: __w/neovim/neovim/build/nvim.AppDir/usr/share/nvim
```

How can I solve this error?

I have found `syntax.vim`
is located in `/home/user/Apps/Neovim/nvim-linux64/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/`
just where I installed NeoVim, but NeoVim is looking for it in another path.
I tried copying syntax.vim to `usr/share/nvim/syntax/syntax.vim`
but the errors still remains.

I tried setting the `VIMRUNTIME` with no success.

Comment: Did you manually configure `$VIMRUNTIME`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this problem by linking the executable inside `/home/user/Apps/Neovim/nvim-linux64/` with a symbolic link.
Using hard links didn't work.
If I called the program from inside `/home/user/Apps/Neovim/nvim-linux64/` neovim worked without errors, but after creating a symbolic link pointing to `/usr/bin` I can use nvim from anywhere without a problem (`E848: Can't open file /__w/neovim/neovim/build/nvim.AppDir/usr/share/nvim/syntax/syntax.nvim`)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ChristianBrabandt you can add the following line at the start of your `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`:

```
let $VIMRUNTIME='/home/user/Apps/Neovim/nvim-linux64/share/nvim'
```